# Need loop to ask user to re enter the file name until correct

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

How am I able to fix the loop to ask the user to retype the filename over and over again if they type in the wrong file name?

```
using namespace std;

void get_input_file(ifstream &in_stream);

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream;

    cout << "Welcome to the Test Grader." << endl;
    get_input_file(in_stream);
}

void get_input_file(ifstream &in_stream) {
    string file_name;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the file name you would like to import the data from: " << endl;
        cin >> file_name;

        in_stream.open(file_name.c_str());  //Opens the input file into the stream}
    }

    while (in_stream.fail()); {
        cout << "Error finding file, try again.\n";
    }

    cout << "Testing: " << endl;
    cout << file_name << endl;
}
```

Comment: Check if `in_stream.open()` failed inside of an endless loop and use `break;` if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this:

```
using namespace std;

void get_input_file(ifstream &in_stream);

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream;

    cout << "Welcome to the Test Grader." << endl;
    get_input_file(in_stream);
}

void get_input_file(ifstream &in_stream)
{
    string file_name;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the file name you would like to import the data from: " << endl;
        cin >> file_name;

        in_stream.open(file_name.c_str());  //Opens the input file into the stream
        if(in_stream.fail())
        {
            cout << "Error finding file, try again.\n";
            continue;
        }
        break;
    } while(true);


    cout << "Testing: " << endl;
    cout << file_name << endl;


}
```

Comment: This is a loop with break in the middle. I normally use:
for(;;) {
   ...
   if (!in_stream.fail()) break;
   cout << "Error";
}

Comment: I just wanted to make it with smallest possible change

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your do while loop does what you'd like it to do.

After the semicolon your loop is over, hence the block behind it is not executed within the loop.

What I think you are looking for is something like this:

```
do {
    cout << "Enter the file name you would like to import the data from: " << endl;
    cin >> file_name;

    in_stream.open(file_name.c_str());  //Opens the input file into the stream}
    if(in_stream.fail()){
        cout << "Error finding file, try again.\n";
    }
} while (in_stream.fail());
```